# Android: How do I access variables that were imported from another activity, and initialized in the onCreate function?

Tags: java, android

I did the following to send values of 2 variables from **first activity** to **second activity** as shown in the following:

```
String name = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.goalcountername)).getText().toString();
String amount = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.clickgoal)).getText().toString();
.
.
.
Intent J = new Intent(this, secondactivity.class);
            J.putExtra("title", name);
            J.putExtra("clickgoal", amount);
            startActivity(J);
```

Then, on the **Second activity** I did the following to unpack what I sent from the **first activity**:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second activity);
        
        Intent J = getIntent();

        //import the string and set the title to said imported string
        String imported_title = J.getStringExtra("title");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.title2)).setText(imported_title);
        
        //import the string, set the goal to said imported number
        String imported_clickgoal = J.getStringExtra("clickgoal");
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.goal)).setText(imported_clickgoal);
    }
```

However, when I try to access the variables **imported_title** and **imported_clickgoal**, it does not work, I am well aware that those are local variables inside of **protected void onCreate** function, but is there a way for me access them, say for example in another function?

I have tried accessing the variables in the **first class** by doing the following but it did not work either, I am not sure why:

`firstactivity.name

OR

first.activity.amount`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `imported title` and `imported clickgoal` variables are not accessible outside of the onCreate function because they are local variables that are only accessible inside the scope of that method.
If you wish to use them in another method inside the same class, define them as instance variables at the class level.